# Installing Perfect-Scrollbar

Tags: jquery, perfect-scrollbar

I am trying to install [this](http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/) `plugin`. I am following [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gbfLazpx/243/) code. But my output is like below. Why it displaying like this ?

[image]

Comment: It appears to be working as expected in Chrome v55 on Mac OS X 10.11.6. Perfect Scrollbar inserts the correct DOM elements and overrides the `overflow:auto;` style as expected. See my screenshot for what I see when running your fiddle: http://imgur.com/a/QlzSw

Comment: Thanks @jamez14. I am using Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 m and Windows 8. I can see the fiddle perfectly. But if I install the plugin in any site I cant see the output perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the link you shared with us, but I'm pretty sure (I used different scrollbar plugins in my projects) that you need to set the container you want to scroll like this:

```
position: relative;
overflow: hidden
```